# Does not recognize Add Collection Mappers from automapper.collection

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I try to use automapper.collection but in the Mapper.Initialize method the AddCollectionMappers method is not recognized

I'm using .net 4.7, automapper 6.1.1, automapper.collection 3.1.1

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrNA2.png)

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding using statement:

```
using AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression;
```